# How to link form data to a GET route

Tags: node.js, forms, express, pug, body-parser

I am pretty sure I am royally messing this up but I am stuck, and have no choice but to ask.

I have this simple pug form:

```
form(id="searchForm", action="/search" method="POST")
        input(type="text" name="keyword")
        input(value='Submit', type='submit')
```

Grabbing the form input is no problem.  Down below gets that done.

```
app.post('/search, (req, res) => {
    var keyword = req.body.keyword
    console.log(keyword) // returns user input
})
```

But this is where I am struggling.  I simply want to take my form data and inject it into `:keyword`. Naturally, I also want that page to show up when I click submit.

```
app.get('/search/:keyword', (req, res) => {
    scraper
        .searchDictionary(req.params.keyword)
        .then(words => {
        res.json(words);
    });
})
```

Basically, this is crawler project that I have to finish, and this is a crucial part to its functionality.  That get request works easy enough.  If I directly type search/enter_keyword, I get all the scraped data in JSON format.  So, that functionality works exactly as it needs to.

The problem is, I want the form input to somehow sync with that route, and basically fulfill that `:keyword` portion of my route.  Sorry if that's not enough info or this is deemed not a good way to do things.  Ask questions if need be.

Comment: I'm not super sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but could you not add scraper.searchDictionary(req.body.keyword).then(...res.json()) to the app.post('/search') route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to the another route:

```
app.post('/search, (req, res) => {
    var keyword = req.body.keyword;
    res.redirect('/search/' + keyword);
})
```

Comment: thanks a ton... I even tried a redirect earlier but obviously, I messed it up!